# Compare two columns categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to pandas and ML in general, I'm working on the Kaggle Titanic competition and I'm trying to see the relationship between the passenger class and whether the passenger survived or not. For this I have the column "Survived" with 0 for "No" and 1 for "Yes", also, the column "Pclass" with categories 1, 2 and 3. So what I want to do is compute the ratio of survived/deceased for each class, however, I can't seem to wrap my head around a way to do this.
So far I have: `data_grouped = train_data.groupby(["Pclass", "Survived"]).size().reset_index() data_grouped.rename(columns={0: 'Count_per_class'})` which gives me a dataframe with the information I need, but I don't know how, based on this, compute the ratios that I'm looking for.

For example, I would like to have something like:

**1: 0.50,
2: 0.25,
3: 0.25** these numbers being the ratio of, as I said, survived/deceased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `df` be your dataset containing info about all passengers. Groupby `PClass` then divide each unique `PClass` value's survived counts (assuming flag `1 == Survived`) by the total count of each unique val df.

```
df.groupby(['PClass']).apply(
    lambda df: 
    df['Survived'].value_counts().loc[1]/df.shape[0]
)
```

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't test the snippet, lmk if something doesn't work out

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question, how could I store this to plot something like Pclass, Ratio with matplotlib?

Comment: IIRC this comes out as a series, so just assign some variable name to the outcome like `result = df.groupby(... Etc.` If you want to plot it, the index of the series would be the x values and y values would be the series itself. If your plotting library takes numpy just call `to_numpy()`